# How to create friendly links in Yii project using Yiinitializr

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii

I try to use Yiinitializr site structure for my Yii project. The structure looks like this:

```
root
--backend
----standart yii folders
----...
----www
------index.php (admin.mysite.com)
--common
----common folders for backend and frontend
----...
--backend
----standart yii folders
----...
----www
------index.php (mysite.com)
```

[Blank Yiinitializr strucure see on github](https://github.com/tonydspaniard/yiinitializr-intermediate)

The question is how to make working URLs like this:

```
admin.mysite.com/invites - in backend
```

and

```
mysite.com/users - in frontend
```

Troubles with routing appeared when i uploaded project on virtual hosting. Backend for example:

```
admin.mysite.com/backend/www/?r=site/invites - working properly
admin.mysite.com/backend/www/invites - working properly
admin.mysite.com/?r=site/invites - working properly
admin.mysite.com/invites - redirects to index
```

Root folder has own .htaccess with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^backend/www/ - [last] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin.mysite.com [nocase] 
RewriteRule (.*) backend/www/$1 [last]

RewriteRule ^frontend/www/ - [last] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !admin.mysite.com [nocase] 
RewriteRule (.*) frontend/www/$1 [last]
```

backend/www/.htaccess have rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

And Yii urlManagers code:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    // uncomment the following if you have enabled Apache's Rewrite module.
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,

    'rules' => array(
        // default rules
        '<page:\w+>' => 'site/<page>',
        '' => 'site/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

Comment: Are `admin.mysite.com/site/invites` working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED AFTER** discussion in the chat:
All problem will be in `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, it equals `/backend/www/index.php`. That's why parsing of request in `CHttpRequest::getPathInfo` is empty value, because $baseUrl (it's a basedir of $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] not `''`) and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`.


Two solutions:

1. Set on the beginning of index.php `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/index.php';`
2. Make that subdomain `admin.example.com` see to the directory `/backend/www/` directly.

Comment: Still redirect to index

Comment: Are you redirecting to `admin.mysite.com/backend/www/index.php` or to `admin.mysite.com/index.php`?

Comment: Running actionIndex, but i don't know how to check to what url exactly redirecting. Hosting support write that from server point of view admin.mysite.com/backend/www/index.php and admin.mysite.com/index.php is the same address

Comment: You may insert into index.php before all code following: `exit(var_export($_SERVER, true))`. Can you show me all strings with url (it's may be REQUEST_URI)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_REQUIRE in ~/www/htdocs/backend/www/index.php on line 13

Comment: Root folder doesn't have index.php. Only .htaccess

Comment: :) set `;` at the end of line 13. So, the code: `exit(var_export($_SERVER, true));`

Comment: посмеемся по-русски :--)
`Partial response in case of too long message:
array ( 'PHPINIDIR' => '/www/u5013', 'PATH' => '/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin', 'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200', 'SCRIPT_URL' => '/composer', 'SCRIPT_URI' => 'http://admin.mysite.com/composer', 'HTTP_HOST' => 'admin.mysite.com', 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP' => 'xx.17.yy.54', 'HTTP_SERVER_ADDR' => 'xx.111.yy.191', 'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'close',`

Comment: `'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6', 'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => 'Apache Server at admin.mysite.com Port 80
', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache', 'SERVER_NAME' => 'admin.mysite.com', 'SERVER_ADDR' => '127.0.0.1', 'SERVER_PORT' => '80', 'REMOTE_ADDR' => 'xx.17.yy.54',`

Comment: `'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '~/www/htdocs/', 'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'support@who.com', 'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '~/www/htdocs/backend/www/index.php', 'REMOTE_PORT' => '26705', 'REDIRECT_URL' => '/backend/www/composer', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.0', 'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET', 'QUERY_STRING' => '', 'REQUEST_URI' => '/composer', 'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/backend/www/index.php', 'PHP_SELF' => '/backend/www/index.php', 'REQUEST_TIME' => 1383140284, 'argv' => array ( ), 'argc' => 0, )`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40257/discussion-between-creator-and-vitalii-del-vorobioff)