# Yii router can't find my controller by using urlmanager in a linux server

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

I have 2 controllers named **UserController** & **AdminController**, they both have index method. The index method renders panel view. They both work in localhost but after upload into a linux server **AdminController** doesn't work and only white page is rendered without any error. This is my urlmanager in **config/main.php** :

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=> 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(                                                            
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',                                                                
),
```

any suggestion to debug?

Comment: Are there any controller works in the server? See on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676821/how-to-create-friendly-links-in-yii-project-using-yiinitializr/19680304#19680304, maybe you have the same problem?

Comment: Yes all controllers but Admin work !

Comment: Add code `exit("ok")` on the beginning of the AdminController and let's see if it printed

Comment: This is the beginning of AdminController.php : exit("ok"); output is empty

Comment: Do you have debugging turned on or off on your index.php? Also do you have display_errors in your php.ini on or off?

Comment: Debugging is on and in the localhost display_errors is on, there is no error in rendered page

Answer (score 0):

Check file permissions of `AdminController`, try to set it to `755`

Comment: I didn't change its permission, I just uploaded it from localhost to sever. To ensure that the file permission is not matter I created a new file in my editor and I did paste hole AdminController source code into that file. nothing changed !

Comment: It's very strange that no error, no "ok" even `exit("ok")` is before class declaration... I haven't any more ideas, maybe try to rename `AdminController` to another name

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not related to Yii router or Linux case sensitivity or file permission or anything else, there was a syntax error in AdminController.

Because Yii uses require to import class files if there is a loading error, the script will not continue.

My syntax was :

```
$todayPays = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('sum(cost) paySum')
            ->from('ka_phish')->where('CURDATE()=DATE(payDate)')->queryRow()["paySum"];
```

The end part of above line is **queryRow()["paySum"]**, which in the localhost runs without any problem but it doesn't in the server. I think this is a php version issue !